# SO_ERROR value after successful socket operation

Tags: sockets, posix

I'm curious about the behavior of the SO_ERROR socket option used with getsockopt() after a successful socket operation

The [Open Group specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getsockopt.html):

> SO_ERROR
>       Reports information about error status and clears it. This option shall store an int value.

Usually I see SO_ERROR used after a socket operation returns -1, but what happens if the previous socket operation succeeded (thus not returning -1).  Does the getsockopt() call fail?  Does it return 0 as the int value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've learned more about SO_ERROR in Unix Networking Programmig Vol 1, it's become clear to me.  SO_ERROR is used to report asynchronous errors that are the result of events within the network stack and not synchronous errors that are the result of a library call (send/recv/connect).  Synchronous results are reported via errno.

**Calling getsockopt() with SO_ERROR after a library call returns -1 is incorrect from the POSIX implementation.**

Learning of the non-blocking connect result via select is an example of discovering when the asynchronous result is ready (which can then be retrieved via SO_ERROR)

Answer (score 3):

It's ok for non-blocking connect, see [connect(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/connect)

> The socket is nonblocking and the connection cannot be completed immediately. It is possible to select(2) or poll(2) for completion by selecting the socket for writing. After select(2) indicates writability, use getsockopt(2) to read the SO_ERROR option at level SOL_SOCKET to determine whether connect() completed successfully (**SO_ERROR is zero**) or unsuccessfully (SO_ERROR is one of the usual error codes listed here, explaining the reason for the failure).

other is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

It's undefined. You should only call this option when you already know that there has been an error. Not as a means to discover whether there was one.